# How to check out a file, but then ignore it from syncs then-after

Tags: git, ignore

For files like `.project` files... i do want those files checked in initially...

however... after the initial git clone, the user will one time only edit this `.project` file (different for each workstation), and then will never touch it again.

I'd like git to then ignore all changes for that file.

However, there is a time when i might need to update the `.project` file that will be created during checkout.

Is there someway to "checkout then ignore all further changes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it [here](http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-trcked-files/).

*Fortunately GIT has a very easy solution for this, just run the following command on the file or path you want to ignore the changes of:*

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

*If you wanna start tracking changes again run the following command:*

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```